# micro-ros agent only starts for the second time after uC manual reset

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am building a launcher for a Micro-ROS application running Zephyr RTOS on STM32. I stumbled upon a situation that happens when the agent is started by the second time after being interrupted by a `ctrl+c` or by a `$ killall micro_ros_agent`. It freezes in the logger setup line, just before the initialization of topics, publishers, subscribers, and services, like this:

```
$ ros2 run  micro_ros_agent micro_ros_agent serial --dev /dev/ttyACM0 
[1639862248.302385] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | running...             | fd: 3
[1639862248.302663] info     | Root.cpp           | set_verbose_level        | logger setup           | verbose_level: 4
```

It only resumes if the microcontroller reset button is pressed:

```
[1639862662.431163] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | fini                     | server stopped         | fd: 3
[1639862662.443154] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | Serial port not found. | device: /dev/ttyACM0, error 2, waiting for connection...
[1639862663.140021] info     | TermiosAgentLinux.cpp | init                     | running...             | fd: 3
[1639862664.207718] info     | Root.cpp           | create_client            | create                 | client_key: 0x59B06063, session_id: 0x81
[1639862664.208181] info     | SessionManager.hpp | establish_session        | session established    | client_key: 0x59B06063, address: 0
[1639862664.254578] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_participant       | participant created    | client_key: 0x59B06063, participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.257543] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_replier           | replier created        | client_key: 0x59B06063, requester_id: 0x000(7), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.260180] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_replier           | replier created        | client_key: 0x59B06063, requester_id: 0x001(7), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.262102] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_topic             | topic created          | client_key: 0x59B06063, topic_id: 0x000(2), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.263761] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_publisher         | publisher created      | client_key: 0x59B06063, publisher_id: 0x000(3), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.265743] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_datawriter        | datawriter created     | client_key: 0x59B06063, datawriter_id: 0x000(5), publisher_id: 0x000(3)
[1639862664.271523] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_topic             | topic created          | client_key: 0x59B06063, topic_id: 0x001(2), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.273199] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_publisher         | publisher created      | client_key: 0x59B06063, publisher_id: 0x001(3), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.275206] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_datawriter        | datawriter created     | client_key: 0x59B06063, datawriter_id: 0x001(5), publisher_id: 0x001(3)
[1639862664.280842] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_topic             | topic created          | client_key: 0x59B06063, topic_id: 0x002(2), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.286361] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_publisher         | publisher created      | client_key: 0x59B06063, publisher_id: 0x002(3), participant_id: 0x000(1)
[1639862664.288642] info     | ProxyClient.cpp    | create_datawriter        | datawriter created     | client_key: 0x59B06063, datawriter_id: 0x002(5), publisher_id: 0x002(3)
```

The necessity of resetting the board every time I need to restart the agent is too inconvenient since the board is inside the robot. Is there a way to prevent it or a way to reset the microcontroller automatically after an agent interruption?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393041/micro-ros-agent-only-starts-for-the-second-time-after-uc-manual-reset/) by [Jefecito](https://answers.ros.org/users/30205/jefecito/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2021-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on the app that you are coding on the micro-ROS side. Of course, if the micro-ROS client tries to connect to the agent and then (after some tries) it desists, the board needs to be reset in order to connect to the agent.

In any case, you can code your application to loop until an agent is found. Even you can ping the agent in order to check the availability and open and close the session accordingly.

Check the reconnection example here: https://github.com/micro-ROS/micro_ros_arduino/blob/galactic/examples/micro-ros_reconnection_example/micro-ros_reconnection_example.ino

---

Originally posted by [Pablogs](https://answers.ros.org/users/62986/pablogs/) with karma: 443 on 2021-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0